# Suppose A, B, and C are subsets of a universal set U. Prove that if A∆C = B∆C, then A = B.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

So far, my idea was to proceed algebraically, rewriting the symmetric differences as

(A ∪ C) − (A ∩ C) = (B ∪ C) − (B ∩ C).

I'm not sure how to manipulate this further, however.

Comment: Hint: Symetric difference is associative, and $X\triangle X=\varnothing$ for all sets $X$.

Comment: Does this mean I can simply group the C terms together to get rid of them? As in, commutative property to turn (A ∪ C) − (A ∩ C) into (A ∪ C) − (C ∩ A), and then associative to turn this into  A ∪ (C − C) ∩ A, and then do this for both sides? This doesn't feel right, if only because it seems too easy.

Comment: For any three sets $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, $(X\triangle Y)\triangle Z= X\triangle(Y\triangle Z)$. For any set $X$, $X\triangle X = \varnothing$. For any set $X$, $X\triangle \varnothing = X$. That's all you need, and yes, it is easy. Don't decompose the symmetric difference into union minus intersection: use its properties.

Comment: I see. Where do I go from A∆C = C∆B? I'm wanting to say that A∆C∆B is true by transitive property, but this doesn't give me the two C's I need to negate it. Then, would it be mathematically correct to say A∆C∆C∆B, subtracting C∆B from the right side of the equation?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be symmetric difference if I use that logic, it would be a set difference. A∆C-C∆B, which still gives me an empty set out of C if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If $A\triangle C=B\triangle C$, then $(A\triangle C)\triangle C = (B\triangle C)\triangle C$. I don't know what you mean by "if I use that logic" or "wouldn't be the symmetric difference".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** For all sets $X$, $Y$, $Z$:

1. $X\vartriangle X=\varnothing$.
2. $(X\vartriangle Y)\vartriangle Z=X\vartriangle(Y\vartriangle Z)$.
3. $X\vartriangle\varnothing = X$.

These are basic properties of the symmetric difference. If you don't know them, then prove them, because they are very useful.

**Proposition.** If $A\vartriangle C=B\vartriangle C$, then $A=B$.

*Proof.*
$$\begin{align*}
A\vartriangle C &= B\vartriangle C\\
(A\vartriangle C)\vartriangle C &= (B\vartriangle C)\vartriangle C\\
A\vartriangle(C\vartriangle C) &= B\vartriangle (C\vartriangle C)\\
A\vartriangle\varnothing &= B\vartriangle\varnothing\\
A &= B.&\Box
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Ah, it was the second step here I was missing. Is the second step mathematically valid simply because the △C is added to both sides?

Comment: @RadiantAine Doing the same thing to equal things results in equal things.

Comment: Gotcha, this makes sense! Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know that

$$A \Delta C = \bar AC + A\bar C$$

By $+$ we denote union of pairwise disjoint sets.

So in our problem we have this equality, this is given:

$$\bar AC + A\bar C = \bar BC + B\bar C \tag {*}$$

Also, I assume you know that

$$U = BC + B\bar C + \bar B C + \bar B \bar C$$

Suppose $x \in A$

Let's look at two cases.

1. If $x \in C$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in AC$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \notin LHS$ of $(*)$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \notin RHS$ of $(*)$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in BC$ or $x \in \bar B \bar C$
   The latter is not possible since $x \in C$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in BC$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in B$
2. If $x \notin C$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in A\bar C$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in LHS$ of $(*)$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in RHS$ of $(*)$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in \bar BC$ or $x \in B \bar C$
   But the former is not possible because $x \notin C$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in B \bar C$
   $\Rightarrow$ $x \in B$

OK, in both cases we proved that $A \subseteq B$

In the same way you can prove that  $B \subseteq A$
(since everything is symmetric here).

So it follows that $A=B$